# Does "Stink Bomb" damage the Paladin when he is the first hero?

Tags: dungeon-lords

Can the Paladin get damage from the Trap card "Stink Bomb" if he is the first hero when activating the Trap?

I don’t have the exact card text, but from my memory (translated from the German edition) it says:

1. Move the first hero to the last position (unless it’s a Paladin).
2. The new first hero gets damage.

As the card says "new", it could be argued that it doesn’t damage the Paladin. The Paladin was and is the first hero, so he isn’t *new* at this position. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Is Stink Bomb from an expansion? It doesn't seem to exist in my original English edition of the game.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Yes, it seems to be from the extension *Festival Season* ([according to this card list](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1086205/card-list)).

Comment: I'd never read it like that. The "new" is to clarify that they're not using the same reference to the "first hero", and that it should be whoever's actually first. I don't know the game context enough to answer specifically though!

Comment: I would read *the **new first** hero* as *the hero **that is now** in the first position*. Probably it was the limited space on the card that led to the shorter but somewhat ambiguous wording.

Answer (score 1):

As @Samthere said, the word *new* is to clarify they are refering to the character that is in the first position after the first effect of the card.
Anyway, let's go to the [rulebook, page 17](https://czechgames.com/files/rules/dungeon-lords-rules-en.pdf), Paladins:

> The paladin is a special adventurer that is **always at the front of 
>   the party**. Any new warrior will push ahead of everyone but 
>   the paladin.

So the card specifies the Paladin won't move so it does not go against this primary rule, but the Paladin will take the damage anyway.